# Angular Ngrx Store and two-way data binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm learning how to use the ngrx/store library in Angular 5 and I noticed an unexpected behavior... Please, help me understand if this is the default behavior for this library, because I really wasn't expecting this at all...

Well, my objective is to create a singleton store for storing application config and multiple states for all my components, so when a component updates the store, all subscribed components receives the updated store.

In one of my components I'm using the following constructor:

```
newItems: any

constructor (
private _store: Store<State>
) {

_store.select('operations').subscribe(state => {
  console.log(state)
  this.newItems = state.newItems
})

}
```

So I grab the current state of my store and set "this.newItems" variable to "state.newItems". I have some inputs in my template binded with some properties of "newItems", like this:

```
itemProperties: any = [
{
  name: 'Description',
  key: 'desc'
},
{
  name: 'Manufacturer',
  key: 'manufacturer'
},
{
  name: 'Model',
  key: 'model'
},
{
  name: 'Observation',
  key: 'genObs'
}
]

<div *ngFor="let prop of itemProperties" class="gen-label-input" [ngClass]="{'filled': newItems[prop.key]}">
    <label>{{prop.name}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="newItems[prop.key]">
</div>
```

I was expecting to need to dispatch an action in my component to actually modify my store, but it seems that the two-way data binding through [(ngModel)] is doing this automatically, without the need of any actions at all! I just modify my input and my store is updated, and the updated version is automagically available through my entire application.

Is this the expected behavior of ngrx/store when I assing one store property to a component variable and combine it with [(ngModel)]?

If yes, this is really good in some cases, as I don't have to create inumerous actions to modify my store properties. But I'm worried this is some kind of error that I'm not being able to identify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems that you wrote your store in a wrong way. It should be immutable. Think twice before utilizing it because it can lead to numerous problems. You shouldn't need to write an action for each of your store's model property just update the whole model each time you need it updated. Utilizing Angular's Form system could be handy in here

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem I was thinking about, it should be immutable. But it seems that if you use the two-way data binding without creating a copy of my store property, it becomes mutable... Well, this is absolutely not the objective of stores at all, but I think this could be useful when I have multiple components that share the same configuration... What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: It's very risky but the world belongs to the bravest :)

Comment: Hahaha ok, thank you for your opinion!  In my application I don't think this is going to be a problem, it's only some arrays and configurations that should be synchronized between 5 different components, so I think I'm using this approach in my favor. Another solution would be to create rxjs BehaviorSubjects and expose them as Observables, subscribing to them in my components and emiting changes via "next()", but the global two-way binding with my store seems to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a copy of items from store when you receive them

```
 this.newItems = state.newItems.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item))
```

And yes, it is expected behavior if value is array or object

Comment: Thank you very much, I was missing this idea of copying the array or object property, and this eliminated the two-way binding with my store. But as this is the deafult behavior, I think this is an easy way to keep multiple components that shares the same configuration synchronized, isn't it? Does this come with any side effect? Thanks!

Comment: Didnt understand about side effects. Yes, Store is used to keep common data for different components. And avoiding its modification by refs - part of developers concerns

Comment: Well, then I think there's no problem at all keeping my store two-way binded to some of my components, as I'd have to trigger those changes manually at some point anyway... Thanks again, your answer was very helpul!

Comment: In that case other components will lose possibility to notice store changes

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but these changes won't trigger any effect besides ngClasses and ngIfs in my DOM, and these properties can be verified in functions to be executed on demand as the store updated them from another component. In cases that I must detect these changes, this solution would definitely not be possible. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the expected behavior and you are right the state should be immutable.

You can use [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze) in dev mode to help you detect when you do something you should not be doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, I think in my situation a muttable state for only some properties (configurations shared between multiple components)  of my store is appropriate, as I don't need complex alterations on these properties, they are just booleans or steing input data that won't need any kind of manipulation. Do you think this is appropriate??

Comment: If it is as simple as loading read only configuration values, you can make a `ConfigurationService` that contains `configuration` object. Once the `configuration` object is fully loaded you can use `Object.freeze(configuration)` to avoid non desired modifications.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that, but those configurations are very dymanic. This is a in-field data collective app for asset management, so users changes configurations all the time as they change location in a fabric, for example. If I use a service, I'd have to create rxjs BehaviorSubjects and subscribe to their methods in all my components to allow configuration sync between all active components, and also multiple functions to update each one of my configurations. I think the muttable store with two-way data bind solution is easier to implement. What do you think about this dynamic scenario?

Comment: You are maybe able to change the state outside a reducer, but can you fire the observables listening on the store to update their values ? Did you try ?

Comment: Yes, they are all updated. When I subscribe to the reducers in a component and do something like this: this.newItems = state.newItems, those two objects starts to share the same scope or something like that, they are the same statement of the same variable. And if I bind a property of this.newItems in an input through [(ngModel)], the two-way binding propagates to this.newItems and to the store object! This is really helpful in some situations, like in this dynamic scenario that I explained.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what you asked by "fire the observables listening on the store". Are you talking about the actions inside switch statement that modifies the store? If yes, they are not required in this situation, as the store properties and my components properties are in sync because of the two-way binding. If any other calculation or business logic had to be activated in response to the store update, this approach would not be appropriate, but my situation is only some inputs and booleans that have to be available and editable in multiple components before I submit to server.

Comment: Can you please make a stackblitz of your usage of the ngrx-store ?

Comment: absolutely! here it is: [link](https://angular-ftdiva.stackblitz.io/). In my opinion this is a really great approach to share two-way binded data between multiple components whit no effort at all!

Comment: and here is the link to access files: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftdiva?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). I don't know if you will be able to access it from your computer, I don't know how stackblitz access control works =S. With this kind of solution you can keep your entire application in sync without thinking about actions, functions, etc, but with the limitations of the lack of change detection in each component, of course =)

Comment: Thank's for the example, it feels so wrong but it works xD. And yes, I think the OnPush detection strategy won't work.

Comment: It definitely feels very wrong, but I haven't noticed any bad side effects by this usage! Like I said, for sharing config variables for DOM elements and for on demand server calls, this works wonderfully! Well, I hope that if this is something really bad to be done, someone alert us here, please. Otherwise, this is a really cool way to easily share variables between components and keep them in sync that I haven't seen in the web in my researches at all... A discovery or a false step directly in an abyss?? hahaha

Comment: For your usage, you might find this librarie more appropriate than the ngrx-store : https://github.com/SebastianM/tinystate

Comment: This is an interesting library! I'm going to take a look at it. Thank you!